# java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException in jenkins kubernetes

Tags: jenkins

Executing Maven build in jenkins pod(container) using jenkins Kubernetes

1. Created a maven build
2. I am cloning from git
3. Then trying to execute the junit scripts

For few builds I faced pom.xml path issue

Later after clone I faced java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

Now directly once the build starts getting this error java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

More Info:

1. I also increased memory but didnt worked

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXSdg.png)

2. I was using the same port for docker Jenkins and local jenkins. I made  com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerContainerWatchdog.enabled=false on ALL the Jenkins servers as per some reference.But still facing the issue